# Why is this problem a question on the topic of permutations/combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am reviewing some random problems about combinations/permutations. I stumbled upon the following:

> In a group of $20$ people, how long will it take each person to shake
> hands with each of the other persons in the group, assuming that it
> takes three seconds for each shake and only 2 people can shake hands
> at a time? What about a group of $40$ people

I don't really understand why is this problem part of problems related to the topic of combinations/permutations.
It seems to me that a person would need to shake hands with $19$ people and hence $19\cdot 3= 57$ seconds. So for for $20$ people it would be $57 \cdot 20 =1140$ seconds.
But the solution states:

> $570$ seconds or $9.5$ mins

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Well, if $A$ has shaken $B's$ hand, then $B$ need not shake $A's$ hand later on.

Comment: There are $\binom{20}2=190$ pairs of people, so there must be $190$ handshakes.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: If I have 5 people (A, B, C, D, E) then: A shakes hands with $4$ (B, C, D, E), B shakes hands with $3$ (C, D, E), C shakes hands with $2$ (D, E) and D shakes hands with $1$ (i.e.E). E has shook hand with all. That is a total of $4+3+2+1=10$. But $\binom{5}{2}=10$. What is for some reason confusing to me is formally connecting that process of counting the decreasing number of shakes i.e. $4+3+2+1$ with the $\binom{5}{2}$ ie selecting $2$ out of $5$ and order does not matter.

Comment: @Jim: It’s easily seen that they produce the same result: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=\frac{n(n-1)}2=\binom{n}2\,.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I thought $$\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}$$ Ah I see now

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: So is the thinking process to start with the summation and figure out it is the combinations or the opposite? $\binom{n}{2}$ is the number of distinct shakes but I am not clear theoretically that it won't produce redundant shakes

Comment: @Jim: Yep: after cancellation that becomes $\frac{n(n-1)}2$.

Comment: @Jim: I find it easier to think directly in terms of the combinations: there is exactly one handshake for each pair of people, and there are $\binom{n}2$ pairs of people, so there must be $\binom{n}2$ handshakes.